# ASP.NET Core Binding case sensitivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, binding

I created CRUD controller. When creating a model, I need to use schema:

```
{ "id": int, "name": string }
```

But the controller also binds the schema

```
{ "Id": int, "Name": string }
```

How can I force the controller bind only lowercase version `{ "id": int, "name": string }` ?

Answer (score 10):

The default `JsonSerializerOptions` values for *web apps* is **case-insensitive**.

Taken from [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing) (see the note):

> By default, deserialization looks for *case-sensitive* property name
> matches between JSON and the target object properties. To change that
> behavior, set JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive to
> true:

> **Note**
>
> *The web default is **case-insensitive**.*

You want to configure the serializer to use `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false` in order to be case-sensitive.

You can configure the options in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    });
```

or in .NET 6 using minimal API:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
});
```

Comment: Bogus.... Docs can be confusing in that sense: default case insensitive is false as by this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=net-6.0 .... anyhow nice find.

Comment: @Stefan while the link does say that, haldo is right and the `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` property is `true` by default using asp.net 6. This could easily be confirmed using postman and the boilerplate Web API code.

Comment: In my case it was `builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true)`